# No such file or directory - /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked/nginx

Tags: nginx, homebrew

When i try to install nginx using brew using command `brew install nginx` getting error which says `Error: No such file or directory - /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked/nginx`

How to resolve this issue? I am using macbook

**Resolved**: using command `brew reinstall nginx`

Answer (score 0):

This helped me solve an issue that was a result of needing to force uninstall valet. If you find that you cannot `valet install` after `valet uninstall --force`, try this.